# Создание html кода с помощью javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Суть задачи: необходимо составить гибкий калькулятор цен на товары и услуги пока что имеется [вот такой](http://skaz-gorod.ru/kalkuljator-tvoego-prazdnika.html). Часто меняются цены, дополнительные услуги и их зависимости друг от друга, не успел сваять как всё надо заново переделывать, при моём очень поверхностном знании JS это очень проблематично. Этот калькулятор для меня высший пилотаж, помогите прыгнуть выше головы :)

Моё решение: запоминать выбор элементов и пересоздавать калькулятор на странице при каждом изменении, для этого как я считаю мне необходимо создавать участок HTML кода удалять его и снова создавать с коррективами с помощью JS.

Comment: А в чём вопрос?

Comment: ну так для того программист и нужет чтоб менять программы по причине изменений реалий)) А то что вы задумали -я не совсем понимаю зачем вам это нада и как вы это себе представляете

Comment: изменять всё из за одной маленькой галочки каждый раз это не разумно. Вопрос в общем то простой как создать html код внутри какого то конкретного тега, например div. Причём необходимо его постоянно модифицировать при изменении информации. 

И заказчик не поймёт за что деньги платятся. Я лучше за день всё сделаю и буду заниматься чем то более полезным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А в чем вопрос? вроде решение написано в вопросе ;)

> И заказчик не поймёт за что деньги
> платятся.

позабавило)

***PS:*** ну вот к примеру:

```
<div id='test'></div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var o=document.createElement('div')
o.innerHTML = 'Привет!'
document.getElementById('test').appendChild(o)
</script>
```

вообще в гугле множество примеров....

Comment: не всё так просто, вот к примеру как мне добавить


o.innerHTML = '<form name="formCalc" id="formCalc1">'

Comment: var form = document.createElement('form')
form.name = 'formCalc'
form.id = 'formCalc1'
o.appendChild(form)

Answer (score 0):

вот вам пару ссылок pure js:

- [document.createDocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createDocumentFragment)
- [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement)
- [Node.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild)

jQuery:

- [jQuery( html, attributes )](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2)
- [Manipulation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/)

Answer (score 0):

Вот здесь есть хороший курс по jQuery
http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3927335

если не ошибаюсь то ответ на : "Вопрос в общем то простой как создать html код внутри какого то конкретного тега, например div. "
будет в уроке № 7

вот если что краткий пример:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <body>
      <div>
         Hello Wolrd!
      </div>
      <script src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
      <script>
         $('<h1></h1>', {
                    text: 'New Insert Text'
                }).appendTo($('div'));
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

не проверял код на практике .. но думаю не ошибся. Добавиться в Div H1 с новым текстом